# Convert a string to a string with each letter converted to a previous letter

Tags: c

I am converting each char in a string to its previous character. 
This is the code that I have written:

```
if (str[index] == 'a')
    strCopy[index] = 'z';
else if (str[index] == 'A')
    strCopy[index] = 'Z';
else
    strCopy[index] = (char)(((int)str[index]) - 1);
```

I am looping over each char and calculating the previous character.

Is there a more neater way to do this in C

Comment: You don't have to convert to `int`. `char` is an integer type.

Comment: Just `strCopy[index] = str[index]-1;`

Comment: No, this is as 'neat'  as it gets. If you know that the characters are in a specific range `'a'..'z'`, you could get rid of an `if` statement by using the modulo operator. But since the character may exist in one of two ranges, you still need to test which range it is, and getting rid of the `if`s would result really hackish code.

Comment: Also remember to add a `'\0'` at the end of `strCopy ` when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a more neater way to do this in C  (?)
> ... each letter converted to a previous letter

First test if the character, as an `unsigned char` is a letter - use `<ctype.h>` functions. We certainly want to avoid converting a `(char) 1` or <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd> from a *string* to a *null character*.

```
unsigned char ch = string[index];
if (isalpha(ch)) {
```

Let us assume we are dealing with [A-Z] and [a-z] only as consecutive characters - as in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

```
  if (isupper(ch)) {
    ch--;
    if (ch < 'A') ch = 'Z;
  } else {
    ch--;
    if (ch < 'a') ch = 'z;
  }

  string[index] = ch;
```

---

A one liner is possible, yet not clearer:

```
string[index] += isalpha((unsigned char) string[index]) ?
    (toupper(string[index]) > 'A' ? -1 : 25) : 0;
```

---

A table lookup is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have come up with:

```
#include <string.h>

...

char tempStr = '\0';

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) 
{
    tempStr = str[i];

    switch(tempStr)
    {
        case 'A':
            str[i] = 'Z';
            break;
        case 'a':
            str[i] = 'z';
            break;
        default:
            str[i] = tempStr - 1;
            break;
    }
}

...
```

Reason why this may be an improvement (i.e. "neater"):

Switch statement becomes an appropriate choice for the conditional statement, since switch statement in C compares integers and it internally much more efficient as C creates a lookup table for it when the code is compiled (though, maybe not as much in this case). It is also be much more readable/elegant than nested if-then-else statements.

Comment: This is essentially the same code as the poster, except that you are using magic numbers rather than character literals. I agree that a switch statement may be more readable than a bunch of if/else. But in the end, a good compiler should produce the same code for both cases.

Comment: Be also aware that your code also sets `sti[i]=stri[i]-1` for the string terminator, so your string will not be a string after this operation. Hint: `sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str)` calculates the length of an array, not the length of a string. Use `strlen` for that.

Comment: Revised accordingly; though, I must insist of using the switch statement due to improved readability.